# Posting rows to controller from Html Table

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a web application using ASP.NET MVC. Basically I have an user input form, which includes an HTML table. The user can add new rows to the table if needed. How do I determine, how many rows there are and how do I post them back to the controller?

Comment: Refer [POST a form array without successful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796)

Answer (score 0):

Count the length of a certain class could work.
So at each row you put like class="count-me" then you could just get the length of "count-me" with javascript!

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you can use the selector $(table tr).length to count the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may use javascript for counting row number and send that with a hidden input field

javascript for row count:

```js
var rows = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
```

Comment: if u didnt have specific Id for table. you may use

getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0] instead of  getElementById(tableId)